# how do i get the id of the selected item in dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`<%= form_for(:offer,:url=>{:controller=>'offers',:action=>'combo'}) do |f|%>`

`<%= f.select :catId_get, options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, "id", "name"), prompt: "Select Category" %>`

I am new in rails.I have a `dropdown` where all categories are there.When i select a category from this `dropdown` i want to get its category id in my controller,so that i can use that id for it's child `dropdown`.

Answer (score 2):

**Select**

Each [select](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) option in HTML has two values -- the `value` and the `label`:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

It's only the value which is passed to your controller. This means if you are able to create the `select` tag in your Rails app with the correct `value` / `label` setup, it will pass the correct data you require.

---

**Rails**

Here's how I'd handle it:

```
<%= form_for :offer, offers_combo_path do |f|%>
   <%= f.collection_select :cat_id, @categories, :id, :name, prompt: "Select Category" %>
```

This will pass the following params to your `categories_controller`:

```
#app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
   def combo
      params[:offer][:cat_id]
   end
end
```

---

**Recommendation**

I'd actually recommend you use the `form_tag` helper for this, rather than `form_for`. Reason being that `form_for` is mainly for ActiveRecord objects, and although you *can* use `:symbols` in the helper, you will really need to use a much less elaborate system

I'd just replace your `form_for` with the following:

```
<%= form_tag offer_combo_path do %>
  <%= collection_select :cat_id, @categories, :id, :name, prompt: "Select Category" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can i get `id` without submitting the form, means after selecting any category because in the same form i have two dropdowns `category` and `sub-category`.

Answer (score 0):

Your id should be accessible by

```
params[:offer][:catId_get]
```

in your controller.